# Something not quite right with application of CSV Module in Python

Tags: python

I have a string that I am trying to write to file where the data has the following format:

```
100.10 89.7 1,891.43 123.99
```

Which I want converting to the following format:

```
"100.10","89.7","1,891.43","123.99",
```

However using the following code (where `filepath` is defined earlier in the code as a text file location and `data2` is a string:

```
csv.register_dialect('sas', delimiter=',',quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

with open(filepath, "w") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, dialect='sas')
    writer.writerow(data2)
```

I am getting this output:

```
 "1","0","0",".",1,"0","8","9",".","7","1","8","9","1",".","4","3","1","2","3",".","9","9",
```

I want to use quotes to mask the presence of possible commas in the data, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my_string = '100.10 89.7 1891.43 123.99'

string_list = my_string.split()
```

And string_list returns:

```
['100.10', '89.7', '1891.43', '123.99']
```

When you do:

```
csv.register_dialect('sas', delimiter=',',quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

with open(filepath, "w") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, dialect='sas')
    writer.writerow(data2)
```

It's splitting data2 by character, so when you read it back in it's reading each character as a separate column. You probably want this:

```
csv.register_dialect('sas', delimiter=',',quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

with open(filepath, "w") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, dialect='sas')
    writer.writerow(data2.split())
```

**Edit**

So I might suggest a different tack, forget about registering a dialect, for me that has always been problematic anyways.

```
string_list = ['100.10', '89.7', '1,891.43', '123.99']
with open(filepath, 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    writer.writerow(string_list)

with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
    print f.read()
```

For me printed:

```
"100.10","89.7","1,891.43","123.99"
```

And

```
with open(filepath, 'rU') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    data = next(reader) # next(reader) gives us the iterable's first row.

data
```

returns:

```
['100.10', '89.7', '1,891.43', '123.99']
```

So when you write, do this:

```
with open(filepath, "w") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    writer.writerow(data2.split()) # *write here
```

You are probably intending to write a bunch of rows, so be sure to either loop through your rows that you want to write, or use `writerows` instead of `writerow`. [See the examples in the documentation.](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#examples)

Comment: Thanks for replying. This works, except that commas within the values are being picked up as delimters. Is the QUOTE_ALL option not meant to prevent that from happening?

Comment: @user3045351 Are there commas in the thousands place?

Comment: @aaronhall...the data is really messy from the yahoo feed..some stock metrics are text, some numeric, some are quoted, some are not, some have ',' in the data, some do not. unfortunately there is no consistent format in the data.

Comment: @aaronhall...what does temp/foo represent?

Comment: @user3045351 that was the file location I created the csv file that I wrote to and read from. It's your file path, just substitute your own.

Comment: @aaronhall...ok. so in my example then i would be sayingstring_list = [data2]?

Comment: @user3045351 No, do `data2.split()` which splits on the white space.

Comment: @aaronhall...yes that seems to have done the trick. thanks for your help. just to check my understanding "string_list = data2.split()
            with open(filepath, "w") as f:
                writer = csv.writer(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
                writer.writerow(string_list)" is taking a string (data2) and converting it to a list split on white spaces then writing it to a text file? is that correct?

Comment: That's 100% Correct. Notice I use the U flag to read, that enables Universal Newlines mode, and was useful when I was getting CSV files from various sources.

Comment: i dont know what universal newline mode is but i will read up on it. thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @user3045351 It's a platform dependancy issue, for newlines: Unix/Linux uses '\n', Windows uses '\r\n', and Mac uses '\r'. I had someone with a Windows computer give me a Mac formatted csv file, somehow. I think it was a test, and they were hoping I'd fail. I try to pass on my learning of best practices all I can, though. :)

Comment: @aaronhall...ah i see, i have removed all the line breaks and special characters using the following 'data2 = data2.replace(r'\r', '').replace(r'\n', ' ').replace('"', '').lstrip(r'b').lstrip(r"'").rstrip(r"'").replace(',', '')'...is there a more elegant way of doing it or is that the best solution?

Comment: @user3045351 There are better ways to remove a lot of chars, but it gets more complicated, you might be better off asking another question, I'll look for it, but try to get your code set up first that includes everything you're trying to control for. And I'm going to make a final update to my post here.

Comment: ok, its fine, dont worry about it, i will revisit it at a later point. just one last quick question in relation to this. how does 'string_list = data2.split()' convert 'data2' from a string to a list? it just looks like it is converting it to another string to me? is 'string_list' a protected keyword for lists?

Comment: @user3045351 string_list is my own madeup word for a list of strings. `.split()` with no arguments splits on all whitespace, which includes spaces, tabs (\t), and newlines (\n, or possibly other combinations depending on your system, which is why I recommend reading in with U). Here's another example: `>>> 'foo bar baz'.split()` which returns: 
`['foo', 'bar', 'baz']`

Answer (score 2):

You are passing a string to `writerow`, so it iterates over characters, putting a comma between each one. The minimal fix is:

```
writer.writerow(data2.split(" "))
```

Alternatively, it is probably more convenient to keep the data in a list rather than making a string in the first place!

Comment: Thanks for replying. Will using the 'QUOTE_ALL' option prevent the data from being split where there are spaces within some of the values? The results being returned will be mostly numeric but in other examples could be something like 'Exxon Mobile'.

Comment: Jon, do you think I'm right? Or do you have more to add?

Comment: @user3045351 no, the `QUOTEALL` applies to the csv export, not the string or the list. I would recommend processing the data into floats, then you only need to quote the strings; you will have to do this at some point to *use* the data anyway.